# Customizing Woocommerce email template colors for specific emails via PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to customize the color of specific email templates.

I'm happy with the basic email templates for simple and variable products on my Woocommerce store (https://snag.gy/tmwv7q.jpg). However, I'm setting up subscriptions using the Woocommerce Subscription extension and would like to change the color palette on select email notifications (just those linked to the Subscriptions extension).

I believe that this snippet of code may be used to change the background color, for instance, in my child theme's functions file. However, this would change all the templates:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_styles', 'custom_woocommerce_email_styles' );
function custom_woocommerce_email_styles( $css ) {
$css .= "#template_header { background-color: #4f7acc; }";
return $css;
}
```

How would I change the coloring for select email templates only? At the very least, the "base color". (From # ed1e24 to #4f7acc).

(I know the text domain for the Subscriptions extension is 'woocommerce-subscriptions'. Not sure if that helps as the correct argument needed.)

If anyone could please guide me I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default WooCommerce email templates by placing files with the equivalent name in your child theme directory.

**Example**

To override the new order email template

1) Copy this file:  `woocommerce/templates/emails/admin-new-order.php`

2) Paste it in your child theme directory as such: `YOUR-CHILD-THEME/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php`.

3) Make desired edits in child theme file.

There reason that I haven't provided you with specific directions as to how you may change the subscription email, is due to the fact that it's a paid extension, and I don't have access to it. If the templates may likely be located in the plugins directory, in which case you would need to search in that location for the file and directory names.

Comment: Hi Ryan. Thanks for your help. I don't want to override templates for the obvious reason that they're subject to future updates. I also realise that with a paid extension, giving a more specific solution is difficult. I guess my question is, is there a way to customise certain email notifications via PHP, and if yes, what would this code look like? If I have the code I can experiment on a demo site until I get a solution.